# I2C Device Registered on CLI but not in Python

Tags: i2c, raspbian-buster, lcd

I have a JANSANE 16x2 1602 LCD I2C that i purchased and am trying to run on a raspberry pi 3 b+.

Following this tutorial

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/python-usage

I am trying to run the below code:

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_rgb_i2c as character_lcd
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = character_lcd.Character_LCD_RGB_I2C(i2c, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)
lcd.message("TEST")
```

However I get the error:

```
ValueError: No I2C device at address: 20
```

When I run i2cdetect I get:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1

     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 27 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Which tells me that the device is being registered.  Can someone please explain the error in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Andyroo, the chip is not the same chip described for the tutorial I was using.

For those who may be in the same situation, try this tutorial:

https://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-i2c-lcd-set-up-and-programming/

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

The address of the board connected to your Pi is 27(hex) and not 20(hex).

The row shows the most significant digit and the column shows the least significant digit of the address in hex.

Going by Amazon, this is the default for the PCF8574T chipset on this board but looking at the pictures, one of the interface cards have a set of three address pins that may let you set the address to match the software but I cannot tell without the manual that matches your board.

From a quick scan of the source, I think the issue is in the `i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)` line where the board library is setting the wrong address for you but without knowing the tutorial you are following I can only guess this is a Micropython issue.

It would help if you can edit your question with links to the instructions and your board (as the one I found was 5V Arduino).

Comment: @Andryoo I'm having trouble finding documentation specific to this board, but the chip is PCF8574T and itthe amazon item pages says I need to download the LiquidCrystal_I2C library.  The Item description does say it works with Raspberry Pi

Comment: Unless your board is the Adafruit one then their code will not work. They have put an I/O expander on their board to save a lot of pins at addr 20.  The LiquidCrystal_I2C is an Arduino library (C or C# not sure).  Anything on the board to change the address?

Comment: thank you, your questions and points helped me find the answer